# CSS Border Transparency issue

Tags: css, image, png, transparency

Here's the fix I used:

> Okay so I got around it by setting the bg color to transparent and
>   using a repeating background image to simulate using "white" for my
>   background.
>
> I first tried to set just the text background to white but that didn't
>   work because only the text was white, the other parts would be the
>   background color.

original question:
I'm having issues with an image I'm using, the transparency works fine
when viewed on my computer but when used as a CSS border the
transparent color disappears and and left with a white background.

```
.blog {
border-width: 27px;
-moz-border-image: url(divborder.png) 27 stretch;
-webkit-border-image: url(divborder.png) 27 stretch;
-o-border-image: url(divborder.png) 27 stretch;
border-image: url(divborder.png) 27 stretch;
font-family: pokemon;
font-size: 9px;
padding: 0px;
margin: 20px;
background-color: #FFF;
```

}

Is there any way around this?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: you can also post your solution below and set it as the accepted answer.

Comment: As a new user I am unable to do this for 8 hours sorry!

Answer (score 1):

have you tried setting an actual border color with an rgba colour which allows transparency? for example:

```
border-color: rgba(128,128,128,0.3);
```

it might help, might not.

Comment: Glad you found a solution